# Sin(int) is broken in Xcode debugger (lldb)

Tags: xcode, debugging, lldb

I have an universal iOS app targeting iOS SDK 6.1, and the compiler is set to **Apple LLVM compiler 4.2**. When I place a breakpoint in my code and run the following I get weird results for `sin(int)`.

For reference, `sin(70)` = `0.7739` (70 is in radians).

```
(lldb) p (double)sin(70)
(double) $0 = -0.912706376367676 // initial value
(lldb) p (double)sin(1.0)
(double) $1 = 0.841470984807897 // reset the value sin(int) will return
(lldb) p (double)sin(70)
(double) $2 = 0.841470984807905 // returned same as sin(1.0)
(lldb) p (double)sin(70.0)
(double) $3 = 0.773890681557889 // reset the value sin(int) will return
(lldb) p (double)sin(70)
(double) $4 = 0.773890681558519
(lldb) p (double)sin((float)60)
(double) $5 = -0.304810621102217 // casting works the same as appending a ".0"
(lldb) p (double)sin(70)
(double) $6 = -0.30481062110269
(lldb) p (double)sin(1) 
(double) $7 = -0.304810621102223 // every sin(int) behaves the same way
```

Observations:

- The first value for `sin(int)` in a debug session is always `-0.912706376367676`.
- `sin(int)` will always return the same value that was returned from the last executed `sin(float)`.
- If I replace `p` with `po`, or `expr` (e.g. expr (double)sin(70)), I get the same exact results.

Why is the debugger behaving like this?

Does this mean that I should type cast every single parameter each time I call a function?

Some more interesting behavior with NSLog:

```
(lldb) expr (void)NSLog(@"%f", (float)sin(70))
0.000000 // new initial value
(lldb) expr (void)NSLog(@"%f", (float)sin(70.0))
0.773891
(lldb) expr (void)NSLog(@"%f", (float)sin(70))
0.000000 // does not return the previous sin(float) value
(lldb) p (double)sin(70)
(double) $0 = 1.48539705402154e-312 // sin(int) affected by sin(float) differently
(lldb) p (double)sin(70.0)
(double) $1 = 0.773890681557889
(lldb) expr (void)NSLog(@"%f", (float)sin(70))
0.000000 // not affected by sin(float)
```

Comment: po command is for printing objects - try 'p' instead. Also, sin accepts parameter in radians, so sin(90) should not be zero

Comment: @Vladimir: It happens with p as well, I updated the code to reflect that. I am aware that sin takes in radians, which is why the first output is weird.

Comment: File a bug with Apple, please!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're walking into the wonderful world of default argument promotions in C.  Remember, lldb doesn't know what the argument types or return type of `sin()` is.  The correct prototype is `double sin (double)`.  When you write

```
(lldb) p (float) sin(70)
```

there are two problems with this.  First, you're providing an integer argument and the C default promotion rules are going to pass this as an `int`, a 4-byte value on the architectures in question.  `double`, besides being 8-bytes, is an entirely different encoding.  So `sin` is getting garbage input.  Second, `sin()` returns a `double`, or 8-byte on these architectures, value but you're telling lldb to grab 4 bytes of it and do something meaningful.  If you'd called `p (float)sin((double)70)` (so only the return type was incorrect) lldb would print a nonsensical value like 9.40965e+21 instead of 0.773891.

When you wrote

```
(lldb) p (double) sin(70.0)
```

you fixed these mistakes.  The default C promotion for a floating point type is to pass it as a `double`.  If you were calling `sinf()`, you'd have problems because the function expected only a `float`.

If you want to provide lldb with a proper prototype for `sin()` and not worry about these issues, it is easy.  Add this to your `~/.lldbinit` file,

```
settings set target.expr-prefix ~/lldb/prefix.h
```

(I have a `~/lldb` directory where I store useful python files and things like this) and `~/lldb/prefix.h` will read

```
extern "C" {
int strcmp (const char *, const char *);
void printf (const char *, ...);
double sin(double);
}
```

(you can see that I also have prototypes for `strcmp()` and `printf()` in my prefix file so I don't need to cast these.)  You don't want to put too many things in here - this file is prepended to every expression you evaluate in lldb and it will slow your expression evaluations down if you put all the prototypes in `/usr/include` in there.

With that prototype added to my `target.expr-prefix` setting:

```
(lldb) p sin(70)
(double) $0 = 0.773890681557889
```

Comment: +1 for thorough explanation. Even though I know nothing of C, it made sense.

Comment: I knew who would be giving the answer :-) - So lldb does not "know" the prototypes even if I include math.h in my source file? Why does this problem not occur if I define a function `double mysin(double x)` in my project? Sorry if these are dumb questions :-)

Comment: Prototypes (e.g. from `<math.h>`) don't end up in the debug information for space reasons (if you think a dSYM is big *today*...) - but your own functions generate full debug information so lldb knows the types of all the arguments and the return type.